# Как остановить главный поток main, пока поработают 2 подпотока созанные ExecutorService?

Tags: многопоточность, java

Имеется код многопоточной программы, работающий корректно с использованием системной многопоточности:

```
 // Main thread
 Thread producer = new Thread(resultDAO);
 Thread consumer = new Thread(resultsLoader);
 producer.start(); // start first added thread
 consumer.start(); // start second added thread
 try {
     consumer.join();
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Необходимо переделать данный код с использованием `java.util.concurrent`, т.е. с программной организацией многопоточности.  Написал:

```
 // Main thread
 Thread producer = new Thread(resultDAO);
 Thread consumer = new Thread(resultsLoader);
 ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
 threadExecutor.execute(producer);
 threadExecutor.execute(consumer);
 threadExecutor.shutdown();
 while (!threadExecutor.isShutdown()) {
     System.out.println("Main THREAD WAIT");
     try {
         threadExecutor.wait(100);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
```

но главный поток продолжает работать при незакончивших работу подпотоках, и затем вступает в конфликт при доступе к БД с подпотоком `consumer`. Что я делаю не так? Как в `java.util.concurrent` сделать аналог `join()`?

Comment: Надо бы обезопасить доступ к БД, а не стараться уйти от возможности  конфликта потоков.

Comment: Согласен, если ориентироваться на реальное приложение, но пока вопрос именно в этом - как остановить основной поток до полного выполнения подпотоков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный ответ:

```
Thread producer = new Thread(reader);
Thread consumer = new Thread(resultsLoader);
ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
threadExecutor.execute(producer);
threadExecutor.execute(consumer);
threadExecutor.shutdown();
try {
    threadExecutor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Спасибо @avp натолкнул!

Comment: Как это может быть правильным ответом, если вы установили время ожидания в непонятно откуда взявшийся `magic number` и, ко всему прочему, [засуппрессили `InterruptedException`?][1]

[1]: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Comment: Изучайте на здоровье.

Answer (score 3):

Я так понимаю, один поток пишет в базу, а второй в это же время пытается прочитать? Если да, то, на мой взгляд, это не правильный подход. Эти действия должны идти последовательно. 
Если вы хотите приостановить поток который запускает два других (producer, consumer), то можно попробовать так:

```
while (true) {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  int active = taskExecutor.getActiveCount();
  if (active == 0) {
    taskExecutor.shutdown();
    return;
  }
}
```

`taskExecutor` - это `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`;

Класс, который запускается с помощью `taskExecutor`, должен имплементить `Runnable` интерфейс. Также он должен анатироваться примерно так: `@Scope(value="prototype")`.
Пример:

```
@Scope(value="prototype")
public class RunnableService implements Runnable{
        @Override
    public void run() {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Запускается таким образом:

```
RunnableService task = ContextHolder.getBean(RunnableService.class);
taskExecutor.execute(task);
```

Comment: Первый поток читает данные из файла и через буфферную очередь передается во второй поток, который перегружает данные в БД. Именно для осуществления этой операции мне необходимо приостановить поток MAIN пока не закончат работу подпотоки.

Comment: если я правильно вас понял, то вариант который я предложил должен вам подойти. Main будет "спать" пока не выполнятся подпотоки. Только одна поправка: если Main должен выполнять что-то еще после выполнения подпотоков, то вместо return пишем код.

Comment: Thread.sleep(1000) как-то некрасиво. Наверное лучше поискать метод ожидания каких-нибудь подходящих событий. 

IMHO в java.util.concurrent должен быть такой механизм(ы). Надо доку внимательно почитать.

Comment: @avp предлогайте :)

Comment: Сходу в [доке](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) увидел метод 

    boolean awaitTermination(long timeout,
                         TimeUnit unit)
                         throws InterruptedException

не то ?

--

Кстати, .wait(), который Вы используете IMHO наследуется от Object. Он отработает только по .notify() на этот объект (у Вас ExecutorService threadExecutor). А кто этот .notify() вызовет ?

Comment: нет, не то. Увидели, да не разобрались зачем он. Кстати, wait() я не предлогал.

Comment: @piratewater, 

    threadExecutor.wait(100); 

да, это не Ваше, это из вопроса @rvm.

Я имел в виду, что надо написать (в программе вопроса)


    threadExecutor.awaitTermination(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

вместо 


    threadExecutor.wait(100);

Comment: Тут вы @avp немножко запутались, сначала вы коментируете "Thread.sleep(1000) как-то некрасиво..", теперь перепрыгиваете на threadExecutor.wait(100); Определитесь, или пишите коменты в нужном ответе дабы не запутать народ. Кстати, threadExecutor.awaitTermination(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) не остановит главный поток, как это требуется. Он заблокирует пул на 100 мс и вернет либо true  либо false взависимости от того, закончили ли выполняться потоки в пуле. Этот метод используется для других целей

Comment: Переключиться уже не удастся, т.к. обсуждение по сути дела, переехало сюда.

Возможно и запутался. Т.е Вы считаете, что:

    threadExecutor.shutdown();
    while (!threadExecutor.isShutdown()) {
        threadExecutor.awaitTermination(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if (слишком много циклов) {
           выход по таймауту
        }
    }

Это не аналог join, о котором спрашивал @rvm ?  Я специально не вставлял все try/catch.

--

По поводу "Thread.sleep(1000) как-то некрасиво..", да эта конструкция будет **безусловно ждать**, а awaitTermination() завершится еще и при завершении потоков.